# Is this an extraneous preposition?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to include the "on?"

> Gap years are best for students to decide (on) their majors.

Comment: I think a  question like this belongs on English@SE.  If the sentence is quoting someone and they forgot to say the word "on" but it is implied by the context, then the standard approach is to put it between square brackets and not parenthesis.  As in [ on ]

Comment: @EDL Questions about what is and isn't correct English grammar tend to be frowned upon at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com). They're more welcome at [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: I often advocate for Stack choice. If they posted here instead of ELL or ELU, then it means they want the expertise of people who write for a living instead of pure grammar correctness. It evolves beyond the matter of pure grammar and falls on adequate communication, style, and word choice. In that regard, GarethN's answer nails it. The extraneous proposition doesn't matter. Conveying the message does.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases feel ugly to me and I would avoid them. I would, instead, go for something like 'make decisions about' or 'select'.
GarethN